# как зделать функцию для клонирования многомерного массива без использования методов именно циклами slice метод я знаю он не нужен надо циклами!

Tags: javascript

var arr = [[11,22],2,3,4,5,6];

```
    var clone = function(arr){
        var copy = [];

        for(var a = 0; a < arr.length; a++){
            for(var b = 0; b < arr.length; b++){    
                    copy.push(arr [b][a]);

            }
        }
        return copy;
    }
    console.log(clone(arr));
```

Comment: Рекомендую: https://stackoverflow.com/a/728694/3841429

Answer (score 0):

Давайте сделаем это на циклах.

Используя оператор `for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { ... }` пройдемся по элементам оригинального массива. Каждый элемент массива `arr[i]` будем проверять не массив ли он вызовом метода `Array.isArray(arr[i])`.

Если оказывается, что это массив `if (Array.isArray(arr[i]) == true) { ... }`, то мы создаем новый массив `const nestedArray = []` и добавляем его в наш массив-копию `copy.push(nestedArray)` и в новом (вложенном) цикле `for(var k = 0; k < arr[i].length; k++) { ... }` добавляем в него элементы вложенного массива `nestedArray.push(arr[i][k])`. Тут надо знать, что массивы это объекты и передаются по ссылке.

Если не оказывается, что `arr[i]` это массив, то в блоке `else { ... }` добавляем его в наш массив `copy`.

Profit

Наша программа будет отлично работать для массивов, состоящих из нуля или более одномерных массивов и/или нуля или более других значений. Массивы "третьего уровня" не будут копироваться. Просто передадутся по ссылке.